# PowerBi failed to load report with authToken

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, powerbi

I'm trying to load a simple report by accessToken.
Everything works fine in the sample: [UserOwnsData](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData)

but I need to use a different login flow by username and password throw my website without redirection to the Microsoft login page.

so I have accessToken and embedUrl. I tested it on the [PowerBi demo](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Dd1.png)
and it is working, but when I moved the same logic to simple asp net core MVC application it crashed.

my index.json

```
const show = function () {
const accessToken =
    "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC...";

const embedUrl =
    "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=2c249fa...";
const models = window["powerbi-client"].models;
const embedType = "report";

const reportConfig = {
    type: embedType,
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    }
};

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = document.getElementById("report-container");

console.log(embedContainer);

// Embed the report and display it within the div container
const report = window.powerbi.embed(embedContainer, reportConfig);
console.log("report", report);
// Report.on will add an event handler for report loaded event.
report.on("loaded", function () {
    console.log("loaded");
});

report.on("error", function (event) {
    const errorMsg = event.detail;
    console.error(errorMsg);
    return;
});
};

show();
```

and Index.cshtml

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div class="report-wrapper col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-12">
    <div
        id="report-container"
        class="report-container col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-12"
        >
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
</div>


<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

I have the next error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

```
ObjectdetailedMessage: "Get report failed"errorCode: "403"level: 6message: "LoadReportFailed"technicalDetails: {requestId: "3f640018-89e9-4bdd-ac6e-c2251034701e", errorInfo: undefined}__proto__: Object
(anonymous) @ index.js:51
```

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981450/power-bi-embed-error-403-forbidden-error-from-server) may helpful.

Comment: @Yinqiu Hi, thanks! I have checked it, but it wasn't helpful for me.

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer?